# A verb tense in the conditionals

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions

I have come up with the following simple sentence:

> If I had been younger I would have had less wrinkles.

It bears the past tense in it and I as understand it is perfectly correct. But if I make it a bit more complex I'm not sure what tense I should use for the 2nd, 3rd etc. verbs in such sentences. For example, lets change the said sentence to this:

> If I had been younger and **exercised** more I would have had less
>   wrinkles and **could** run a marathon.

Is that sentence correct? The thing that bothering me, whether it is correct to use just "exercised" & "could" and not "had exercised" & "could have".

Comment: The sentence is most likely  going to be read as *If I had been younger and [had] exercised more...* Since this is the case *could run* sounds strange here, especially after *would have had*. If the if-clause was  only  *If I exercised more*, then *could run* would be fine.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, and if it is "could have run"? Does it sound correct to you?

Comment: Yes, *could have run* would be correct.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, so I should repeat this pattern in all verbs I plan to use in the conditional. Got it. I thought maybe only the first verb should be in the "improved" past tense and others could be without these additional words.  Turned out I was wrong. Could you please compose your comments into an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: It's not that easy. Native speakers use a variety of combinations of verb forms in conditional sentences. What you have asked about, though, is using two verb forms (past perfect *had been* and simple past *exercised*)  in the if-clause to set up two different conditions, and this is something we don't usually do, and it would be rare to see it on a test. My comment was only to say that the sentence would normally be read as two past perfects.

Comment: @Alan Carmack: Since I would assume a deleted ***had** exercised* (as would you, apparently), I'd also naturally assume a deleted *could **have** run* in the final clause of OP's second example. But mainly I would question whether Past Perfect is necessary *anywhere* in the text. Exact context might affect this, but it's almost never a good idea to get into the position where you *keep* repeating Past Perfect usages in pursuit of some hypothetical "tense consistency".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> If I had been younger and exercised more I would have had less wrinkles and could run a marathon.

is odd because of the mixing of tenses.

> If I had been younger, I would have had less wrinkles *(in the photo)*.

makes sense as past perfect.

> If I exercised more, I could run a marathon.

makes sense in the present.

You could move everything to the present

> If I **was** younger and **exercised** more, I **would have** less wrinkles and **could run** a marathon.

or move everything to the past

> If I **had been** younger and **had exercised** more, I **would have had** less wrinkles and **could have run** a marathon.